# file_get_contents попытка открыть домен с которого и запускается этот скрипт

Tags: php

Есть сайт
http://site.ru

Есть скрипт

```
if( $_GET['a'] == 5 ){
    echo 'A = 5';
}

$r = file_get_contents('http://site.ru?a=5');
var_dump($r);
```

И у меня уходит в бесконечную загрузку страницы.

Почему так происходит, и как мне с сайта site.ru отправить запрос на site.ru?params?

Comment: потому что скрипт запрашивает рекурсивно сам себя? казалось бы, очевидное-невероятное.

Comment: @teran действительно, я забыл завершить работу скрипта при проверке $_GET. Вот тупанул